# Getting error while building in xcode error: non-portable path to file

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, mobilepush-ios, xcode

After migrating to SFMCSDK to v8 everything seem to work fine. But now I get the following error when building the project:

```
<module-includes>:2:9: error: non-portable path to file '"Headers/SFMCSdk-Swift.h"'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk
#import "Headers/SFMCSDK-Swift.h"
        ^
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "Headers/MarketingCloudSDK.h"
        ^
/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-aykmzqfhlfnudvgbhvfbjmwbcfgh/Build/Products/DebugInhouse-iphonesimulator/MarketingCloudSDK.framework/Headers/MarketingCloudSDK.h:14:9: note: in file included from /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-aykmzqfhlfnudvgbhvfbjmwbcfgh/Build/Products/DebugInhouse-iphonesimulator/MarketingCloudSDK.framework/Headers/MarketingCloudSDK.h:14:
#import <MarketingCloudSDK/MarketingCloudSDK+Base.h>
        ^
/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-aykmzqfhlfnudvgbhvfbjmwbcfgh/Build/Products/DebugInhouse-iphonesimulator/MarketingCloudSDK.framework/Headers/MarketingCloudSDK+Base.h:12:9: error: could not build module 'SFMCSDK'
#import "SFMCSDK/SFMCSdk-Swift.h"
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'MarketingCloudSDK'
```

It seems that the error has something to do with the file names? Can someone help me out or encountered the same problem

**error: non-portable path to file '"Headers/SFMCSdk-Swift.h"'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk
#import "Headers/SFMCSDK-Swift.h"**

Comment: Did you ever figure this out seeing this issue myself with the SPM version